# VS: How to change IntermediateOutputPath when using ActiveX/COM component

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, activex

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, trying to import an ActiveX control. If I change the intermediate output path in any way, I get an error message—"Failed to import ActiveX control, please ensure it is properly registered"—and the project fails to compile. If I leave the intermediate output path as its default value, the control is imported and the project is successfully built.

I've tried modifying both the `IntermediateOutputPath` and `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` properties without success. Is anything else that I can tweak to get the project to compile with a different intermediate output path?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hard to make this fail intentionally, what did you type??

Comment: I tried both `<IntermediateOutputPath>..\..\build\obj\MyAssembly\Debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>` and `<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>..\..\build\obj\MyAssembly\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>`.

Comment: Okay, so I've narrowed it down to paths containing '.' or '..'—any other paths seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Did a bit more digging, and I was able to narrow down the problem to paths containing '.' or '..'

Thus, with the magic of property expansion:

```
<IntermediateOutputPath>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('..\..\build\obj\MyAssembly\Debug\'))</IntermediateOutputPath>
```

Having the absolute path seems to do the trick.